# Unzip only files that start with a certain word

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, zip, unzip

I have a zip archive (let's call it archive) and let's say I want to go through some directories and finally extract ONLY the files that start with the word 'word'. Some thing similar to:

`archive.zip/dir1/dir2/word***.csv`

What is the command that could do this without having to extract the whole file (very big file)?

I tried this command line:

```
unzip -p archive.zip dir1/dir2/word***1.csv >destination
```

But this only extracts one file not all files that start with 'word'

Comment: Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14125/25919) please.

Comment: It helped extract a specific file. I want to extract all files that start with 'word'. There are many. I updated the question accordingly

Comment: maybe something like `grep` but I can't find how

Comment: On Linux I would put the wildcard expression to match the file in quotes. So something like this **unzip "\*/word\*.csv"**

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
unzip -p archive.zip dir1/dir2/word*1.csv >>destination.csv
```

The `>` truncates file `destination.csv` to zero length giving you the impression that only one file was unzipped, while `>>` creates the file if not present, otherwise appends to it which is the required behavior.

<sub>**Reference :** Check [I/O redirection](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)</sub>

Comment: how do extract them in a directory? I get `Acess denied` even though I have full control permissions